# Why does O(1 + 2 + ... + n-1 + n) = O(n^2)?

Tags: asymptotics

Looking at the example on [this page](http://www.cs.ucr.edu/~jiang/cs141/recur-tut.txt), I see that we can solve the recurrence relation

> T(n) =  T(n-1) + O(n)

like this:

> T(n) =  T(n-1) + O(n)
>                =  (T(n-2) + O(n-1)) + O(n)
>                =  T(n-2) + O(n-1) + O(n)
>                =  T(n-3) + O(n-2) + O(n-1) + O(n)
>                   ...
>                =  T(1) + O(2) + ... + O(n-1) + O(n)
>                =  O(1 + 2 + ... + n-1 + n)
>               =  O(n^2)

This makes pretty good sense until

> ```
>          =  O(1 + 2 + ... + n-1 + n)   
>         =  O(n^2)
> ```

Why would it be O(n^2)?

Comment: Hint: Compute a simple expression (in terms of $n$) for the sum $1 + \ldots + n$.

Comment: The exact value of $1+2+\ldots+(n-1)+n$ is known since it is an arithmetic series.  Look at the explicit formula for it.

Comment: Christopher A. Wong, 1 + 2 + 3 = 6, which isn't 3^2. ???

Comment: $\sum_{i=1}^ni=\frac{(n+1)n}{2} = O(n^2)$. Big O notation doesn't mean that $1+2+\cdots n = n^2$ only that it is at best asymptotically proportional.

Comment: $1+2+\cdots+n=\frac{1}{2}n^2+\frac{1}{2}n=O(n^2)$. (Do you know what big O notation means OP?)

Comment: arctic tern, I'm very new to this type of math, but I my understanding is that Mosquite's comment means that the function ((n+1)*n) / 2 does not grow faster than the function n^2? I don't see how you would know that.

Comment: If you see $f(n)=O(g(n))$, what that means is there exists a constant $C$ such that $f(n)\le Cg(n)$ for all but finitely many $n$. Indeed, $\frac{1}{2}n^2+\frac{1}{2}n\le \frac{1}{2}n^2+\frac{1}{2}n^2=n^2$, so the value $C=1$ works. Read about it: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation